# How i can use "if" with exceptions on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I have code like this:

```
    a = 0
try:
    b = 2/a
    print(b)
except Exception:
    if (Exception == ZeroDivisionError):
        print("lol")
    else:
        print(Exception)
```

How I can do, that my programms print "lol" if error is ZeroDivisionError?
My programms print(Exception), even if errors is ZeroDivsionError

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the caught exception to a name first.

```
a = 0
try:
    b = 2 / a
    print(b)
except Exception as exc:
    if isinstance(exc, ZeroDivisionError):
        print("lol")
    else:
        print(exc)
```

However, I would recommend just catching a `ZeroDivisionError` explicitly.

```
try:
    b = 2 / a
    print(b)
except ZeroDivisionError;
    print("lol")
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
```

`except` clauses are checked in order, so if some other exception is raised, it will first fail to match against `ZeroDivisionError` before successfully matching against `Exception`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're testing the exceptions incorrectly. Your code isn't checking what exception is thrown.

`Exception == ZeroDivisionError` is comparing if those two classes are the same. They aren't though, so that will always result in `False`. You want something closer to:

```
try:
    b = 2/0
    print(b)
except Exception as e:  # e is the thrown exception
    if isinstance(e, ZeroDivisionError):
        print("lol")
    else:
        print(Exception)
```

Doing manual type checks like this isn't great though if it can be helped. This would be better by having two `except`s:

```
try:
    b = 2/0
    print(b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("lol")
except Exception:
    print(Exception)
```

Although, in most cases, you don't want to catch all `Exception`s unless you need that functionality for logging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
a = 0
try:
    b = 2/a
    print(b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("lol")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

However, you should not just catch "all" exceptions, so it is better to leave out the second part.